# Assigning a proportion of a variable to be missing based on the probability of other variables (creating a MAR mechanism) in R

Tags: r, missing-data

In R, I would like to create a variable with 10% missing data and where the missing data is MAR.

For example let stage be a binary variable (i.e., stage = {0,1}). It is fully observed. However, I would like to assign 10% of the observed values to be missing, and the probability that they are missing is given by the distibution of other variables.

Please see code below for data:

```
# Set the seed
set.seed(1234)

# Number of observations
n <- 1000

# Create age variable
age <- 100*rbeta(1000,10,5)

# Create sex variable
sex <- rbinom(1000,1,0.45)

# Create comorbidity variable
cmb <- rbinom(1000,1,prob=plogis(0 - 2*(age/100)))

# Create stage variable
stage <- rbinom(1000,size=1,prob=plogis(0 + 0.9*(age/100) + 0.6*(cmb)))
```

How can I assign 10% of the stage variable to be missing, and where the probability the value is missing is based on age and comorbidity?

I am also looking to be able to change the proportion of missing data easily.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a long-winded way...

Create an ID variable:

```
id <- 1:n
```

Create a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id,age,sex,cmb,stage)
```

Create the name of the variable that will be stage but with 10% missing

```
df$stage.mar10 <- df$stage
```

Of the IDs in the data frame, sample 10% (i.e. `n*0.1`) with probability related to age and comorbidity, and save it as a vector called stage.mar10.id

```
stage.mar10.id <- sample(df$id,n*0.1,prob = plogis(-2.5 + 0.8*(df$age/100) + 0.2*df$cmb))
```

Create a loop to cycle through the sample IDs that match those in the data frame. For each ID that matches, assign the `stage.mar10` variable to take the value `NA`

```
for (i in 1:(n*0.1)) {
      df$stage.mar10[df$id==stage.mar10.id[i]] <- NA 
}
```

Check that it has worked:

```
table(df$stage.mar10)
summary(df$stage.mar10)
```